# django rest_framework drf-social oauth 2 error: invalid client

Tags: django-rest-framework, oauth-2.0

I following this tutorial https://github.com/wagnerdelima/drf-social-oauth2/tree/32fe4e4f871777eec4a835ddd37ce2fb50712267 for my rest API

In

> Testing the Setup

```
curl -X POST -d "client_id=<client_id>&client_secret=<client_secret>
&grant_type=password
&username=<user_name>&password=<password>" http://localhost:8000/auth/token
```

I did try to request for my own token

```
curl -X POST -d "client_id=<nBezU5O1OJT74Vt7bItsbdTgoUqcY4ytJuUcpibO>
&client_secret=<pbkdf2_sha256$390000$mSUCDwLkV3iY4fYjAgEEMq$91mdrFYgz3mj5mayJxT6wcjPFLpMS1Hc3Z4TNl7PySc=>
&grant_type=password
&username=<admin@gmail.com>&password=<admin>" http://localhost:8000/auth/token
```

but it's saying

```
{"error":"invalid_client"}
```

I modify the user model to eliminate the username and use email address instead

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

objects = CustomUserManager()

def __str__(self):
    return self.email
```

Please help

Edit:
In my django's terminal it's saying

> Unauthorized: /auth/token

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `<>` from the value of `client_id` and then try again. `client_id=<client_id>` means that `clinet_id=CLIENT_ID` not `client_id=<CLIENT_ID>`. I hope this resolves the issue.